# C++ Missing words in Output File

Tags: c++

Below is my program that inputs a file into a stack then output into a file in reverse order, It runs as it is supposed to yet it leaves out some words when it output.

UPDATE** It leaves out the words that start the doubling of the stack such that it doesn't insert the 11th term after the 10th term when the size of the Stack is 10; 
I have tried to edit the increase Stacksize function by doing " i <= topStack " yet that causes an compiler error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
//#include "ArgumentManager.h"
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;
string stripSpecials(string str)
{
    int i=0,len=str.length();
    while(i<len)
    {
        char c=str[i];
        if(((c>='A')&&(c<='Z'))||((c>='a')&&(c<='z')) || c == '\'')
        {
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            str.erase(i,1);
            --len;
        }


    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

//  ArgumentManager am(argc, argv); //Instantiating parser for command line arguments
    const int STACK_SIZE=5;
    int count = 0;
    //create and link input...
//  ifstream infile(am.get("A").c_str()); // file to read from, getting name from command line
//  ofstream outfile(am.get("C").c_str()); // output file, getting name from command line
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("input.txt");
    //error message for file open fail
    if (infile.fail())
        cout << "Error opening input file.\n";

    //...and output files
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("output.txt");
    if (outfile.fail())
        cout << "Error opening Output file.\n";

    arrayStack<string> myStack(10);
    std::string word,final_word;
    while (infile >> word)
    {
        final_word = stripSpecials(word);
        myStack.push(final_word);

    }

    while(!myStack.stackIsEmpty())
    {
        word = myStack.top();
        myStack.pop();
        outfile << word <<" ";
    }

    outfile << endl;
    outfile << myStack.count;
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The Stack.H file

```
//ARRAY BASED STACK TEMPLATE
#ifndef H_ArrayStack
#define H_ArrayStack

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class arrayStack {
private:

    int topStack; // the top of the STACK
    void stackCopy(const arrayStack<Type>& newArrayStack);
    Type *list; // array based needs pointer to hold the stack element
    static const int growthFactor = 2;
    static const int initialMaxSize = 10;

public:
    int count; //Count how many times the stack doubled
    int maxStackSize; // the maximum height of the STACK
    const arrayStack<Type>& operator=(const arrayStack<Type>&);

    void stackInitialize() {
        topStack = 0;
    }
    ; //Ensure the array stack is empty
    bool stackIsEmpty() const {
        return (topStack == 0);
    }
    ; //check if stack is empty, is const so will not be messed with
    bool stackIsFull() const {
        return topStack == maxStackSize;
    }
    ; // just like line 8 except check if it is full

    void push(const Type& word); // add a word to the array STACK
    void pop(); //remove a word from the array and increment the top

    Type top() const; //returns the top of the STACK
    void increaseStackSize(); // double the size of stack when stack becomes full

    arrayStack(int size); //the default constructor
    arrayStack(const arrayStack<Type>& newArrayStack); // the copy constructor which allows a new STACK
    ~arrayStack() {
        delete[] list;
    }
    ;
    // it is an array so to ensure no memory leaks the stack must be deleted after use
};
template<class Type>
void arrayStack<Type>::push(const Type& word) {
    if (topStack != maxStackSize){
        list[topStack++] = word; // adding a new word to the STACK
    }
    else
        increaseStackSize();
        count++;


}
template<class Type>
void arrayStack<Type>::pop() {
    if (!stackIsEmpty()) {
        topStack--;
        count--;
    }
}
template<class Type>
Type arrayStack<Type>::top() const {
    if (topStack == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return list[topStack - 1];
}
template<class Type>
arrayStack<Type>::arrayStack(int size) {
    maxStackSize = size;
    count = 0;
    topStack = 0;
    list = new Type[maxStackSize];
}
template<class Type>
void arrayStack<Type>::stackCopy(const arrayStack<Type>& newArrayStack) {
    delete[] list;
    maxStackSize = newArrayStack.maxStackSize;
    topStack = newArrayStack.topStack;
    list = new Type[maxStackSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < topStack; j++)
        list[j] = newArrayStack.list[j];
}
template<class Type>
arrayStack<Type>::arrayStack(const arrayStack<Type>& newArrayStack) {
    list = NULL;
    stackCopy(newArrayStack);
}
template<class Type>
const arrayStack<Type>& arrayStack<Type>::operator=(
        const arrayStack<Type>& newArrayStack) {
    if (this != &newArrayStack)
        stackCopy(newArrayStack);
    return *this;
}

template<class Type>
void arrayStack<Type>::increaseStackSize() {
    maxStackSize = growthFactor * maxStackSize;
    Type* temp = new Type[maxStackSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < topStack; i++)
        temp[i] = list[i];

    delete[] list;

    list = temp;


}
#endif
```

Here is the input and output file where the error occurs

INPUT FILE: Once upon a time, there was a little girl who lived in a village near the forest. Whenever she went out, the little girl wore a red riding cloak, so everyone in the village called her Little Red Riding Hood.

OUTPUT FILE: Hood Riding Red Little her called village the in everyone so cloak riding red a wore girl little ***the*** out went she Whenever forest the near village a in ***lived*** who girl little a was there time a upon Once 
2

(IGNORE THE 2, IT IS FOR KNOWING HOW MANY TIMES THE STACK DOUBLED)
THE Bold and Italicized is the words missing in the output file.

Comment: What efforts have you made to debug the code and determine where the error is?

Comment: @Steve, I have converted the strip special to a for loop and replace the special character with NULL to see if it was deleting the entire word.I went through the stack template and see if the count variable was causing it by deleting the count and running it again. Both to no avail, at this point I am trying more things, yet want to see other possible solutions. Two heads are better then one.

Comment: tried to cout it, yet the missing words dont output either

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugging software  that almost certainly came with your development environment looking for where the code does something unexpected?

Comment: Count the words and you'll quickly see that the missing words are the words that trigger a resize.

Comment: @user4581301, yeah I caught that, yet I can't seem to see what I must insert in the else statement

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
void arrayStack<Type>::push(const Type& word) {
    if (topStack != maxStackSize){
        list[topStack++] = word; // adding a new word to the STACK
    }
    else
        increaseStackSize();
    count++;
}
```

Notice, you are not adding the word when increase the stack size. Yet this is a call to `push`.

I would add, the give away is that you were loosing an occasional word; and what were you doing occasionally in your code?

So:

```
template<class Type>
void arrayStack<Type>::push(const Type& word) {
    if (topStack == maxStackSize){
        increaseStackSize();
    }
    list[topStack++] = word; // adding a new word to the STACK
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Your giveaway is throwing me for a loop. Im thinking too hard

Comment: I'm not sure what, but by your last comment above. Just `if( topStack == maxStackSize)` increase the size. Then add the word always.

Comment: So you saying to list[topStack] = word when topStack == maxStacksize

Comment: I've appended my answer. I must ask, did you write the code you posted yourself? Or, was the assignment to debug and fix some given code?

Comment: I wrote the code, I inserted list[topStack] = word after increase size so it doesnt throw away the word it is holding on but input it

Comment: Ok then, you have it fixed! Some times you can not see the forest through the trees. That is when you step back, and take a breath.